# get date object in java from a date string

Tags: java, mysql, date, simpledateformat

I have a jquery datepicker on my page :

```
$( "#dob" ).datepicker({
        yearRange: "-100:+0", 
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showAnim: 'slideDown',
        minDate: '-100Y',
        maxDate: '-1D'
    });
```

I am getting dob string as : `25-12-1988` in my servlet.

i tried  this :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
            try {
                ud.setDob(formatter.parse(dob));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

to insert this in Db i am doing this :

```
pstm.setDate(9,new java.sql.Date(ud.getDob().getTime()));
```

and in db i got this : `1988-01-25 00:00:00` which is incorrect.

datatype of column is `datetime`

where is the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mm` is "minutes". "Months" is `MM`:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

(See [the javadoc for `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).)

Comment: Um, are you going to provide the *fixed* format instead of just the broken one?

Comment: can i make sure before parsing that the string is in correct format----
for example if i would get string like this : 25/12/1988 or 25-12-88
then it will through an exception ??

Comment: @JAVAGeek: For `25/12/1988`, you don't need to do anything special; it will automatically raise an exception. `25-12-88` is trickier, because as far as `SimpleDateFormat` is concerned, `88` *is* a valid year. You can either use a regular expression to ensure that it matches `\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d` (e.g. `if(! Pattern.matches("\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d", dob)) { throw new Exception(); }`), or else check afterward to make sure that the date is within a sensible range. You'll probably also want to call `formatter.setLenient(false)` so that it's stricter about getting a date that actually exists.